# MySQL - avoid NULL on a divide by zero

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query to retrieve and calculate sales from 2 given periods, their actual growth, and their index growth.

For reference index growth is `sales growth % + 100`. So if an item *grew* by 8 percent, it's index would be 108, just as if it *contracted* 8 percent, the index would be 92.

The problem arises when the first comparable year has 0 sales, and hence the actual growth value is divided by 0 and `NULL` is returned for addition to 100.

**How can I stop the query from returning NULL on a divide by zero, and have it return 0?**

This is part of a PHP application, and as such, if the solution would be better handled in the application layer, please suggest accordingly in any answers.

```
SELECT 
    product,
    SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS `period1`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2014 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS `period2`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2014 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS `growth`,
    (((SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2014 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END)) / 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END))) * 100) + 100 AS `index`
FROM
    productlevel_data AS a
WHERE
    `group` = 'Confectionery'
        AND class = 'Confectionery'
        AND category = 'Confectionery'
        AND subcategory = 'Seasonal'
        AND brand = 'brand'
        AND destination LIKE '%'
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: `WHERE sales != 0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `coalesce` on the whole expression :

```
coalesce( <expression>, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`NULLIF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and [**`COALESCE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```sql
COALESCE(
(((SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2014 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) 
  - 
 SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END)) 
  / 
 NULLIF((SUM(CASE WHEN yr = 2013 THEN sales ELSE 0 END))) * 100),0) + 100, 0) AS `index`
```

The use of `NULLIF` helps avoid the *divide by zero* error: if the denominator is `0` then the whole expression evaluates to `NULL`. The `COALESCE` used turns this `NULL` value to a `0` as expected.

**Note:** It turns out that, *unlike* other RDBMS like SQL Server, MySQL *does not throw an error* in case a division by zero takes place, *but* returns `NULL` instead. Hence, the usage of `NULLIF` is redundant in this case.

Comment: This answer gives me an error of - *incorrect parameter count for nullif* - Is there something missing there?

Comment: @AdamCopley `NULLIF` takes *two* arguments: the `SUM` expression **and** the `0` value.